# SAPUI5 column summing

Tags: html-table, sapui5

I developed a SAPUI5 table on frontend having 4 columns, now I need to show the total sum of 1 column. If anyone knows the code related to this please help me

Controller code

```
onInit: function () {
var oTable = this.byId("producttable"); 
oTable.addStyleClass("myCustomTable");  
    //column list item creation
    var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
            new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{Plant}"
            }),
            new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{PlantDesc}"
            }), 
            new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{parts: [ {path: 'NetAmount'}, {path: 'currency'}],type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',formatOptions: {showMeasure: false, maxFractionDigits: 0,roundingMode: 'away_from_zero'}}"
            })
         ]
    });
    var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSALES_PLANT001_SRV/";
    //Adding service to the odata model
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, false);
    //Setting model to the table
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
        path: "/ZSalesheaderSet",
        template: oTemplate
    });
```

I am getting the following errors in console

> sap-ui-core.js:187 Assertion failed: could not find any translatable
>   text for key 'Total Sales-Yesterday' in bundle
>   './i18n/i18n.properties'  Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 503 ()

Comment: Hi Arun, try to use the code proposed by Erch in updateFinished event of the table. see link below
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/events/updateFinished

Comment: Does the app work with _OData V4_? Or _V2_? Or do all relevant data exist already on the client-side? What kind of "table" is it about? Is it `m.Table`, `ui.table.Table`, `.AnalyticalTable`, ...? Would be nice if the question could be enhanced accordingly.

Comment: OData v2  is using.it is  m.table

Answer (score 0):

```
getSum: function() {  

    var sum = 0, items = this.getView().byId("tableId").getItems();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        sum = sum + items[i].getBindingContext("urBoundModel").getObject().urColumn

    }

    return sum;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, tried this code but i am not getting any output

Comment: dont paste code in comments, edit it into your question with a codebox pls, noone can read it like that

Comment: depending what datatype your column has you maybe need to cast it to int first

Comment: console showing some errors.i am using odata service here

Comment: first of all use xml views not js views, 2nd dont add the remote service in the js part, do so in the manifest and 3rd how did you try to implement my code? and 4th add the errors to the question

Comment: i am using xml view,the code i posted is controller. already added the service in manifest also. tried to put the code in between  the table controllers

Answer (score 0):

If you have bound the table to a Odata or JSON model. Just Iterate over your items and sum the bound property of the column.